# Quais as diferenças entre printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf, printf_s e fprintf_s?

Tags: c, printf

Pesquisando notei que existem varias variações do `printf`, mas não entendi quais as diferenças e qual usar em determinada circunstância.

Gostaria de saber a finalidade de cada um com suas diferenças e como podem ser usados.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Todos são definidos em `<stdio.h>`:

```
int printf( const char *format, ... );                                                 <C99
int printf( const char *restrict format, ... );                                         C99+
```

`printf` escreve no *stream* de saída `stdout`.

```
int fprintf( FILE *stream, const char *format, ... );                                  <C99
int fprintf( FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ... );                 C99+
```

`fprintf` escreve em um *stream* de saída definido por `stream`.

```
int sprintf( char *buffer, const char *format, ... );                                  <C99
int sprintf( char *restrict buffer, const char *restrict format, ... );                 C99+
```

`sprintf` escreve em um buffer de caracteres definido por `buffer`. O comportamento é indefinido se a *string* e mais seu terminador forem maiores que o *array* apontado.

```
int snprintf( char *restrict buffer, int bufsz, const char *restrict format, ... );     C99+
```

`snprintf` escreve na string `buffer`, até o máximo de `bufsz - 1`, terminando com nulo, a não ser que `bufsz` seja zero. Se for zero, nada é escrito, mas o número de *bytes* que seria escrito é calculado e retornado de qualquer maneira. Neste caso específico, `buffer` pode ser ponteiro nulo

```
int printf_s( const char *restrict format, ...);                                        C11+
int fprintf_s( FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...);                C11+
int sprintf_s( char *restrict buffer, rsize_t bufsz, const char *restrict format, ...); C11+
int snprintf_s( char *restrict buffer, rsize_t bufsz, const char *restrict format, ...);C11+
```

Estas funções sufixadas por `_s` são equivalentes às primeiras quatro, mas os seguintes erros são detectados nestas versões, e chamam o *handler* de *constraint* instalado:

- o especificador `%n` está presente no formato
- qualquer argumento correspondente a um `%s` é ponteiro nulo
- formato ou buffer é ponteiro nulo
- `bufsz` é zero ou maior que `RSIZE_MAX`
- erros de conversão de caractere
- (apenas para `sprintf_s`) a string com terminador é maior que `bufsz`

**Nota:** a disponibilidade de `fprintf_s`, `sprintf_s`, e `snprintf_s` só é garantida se a implementação definir `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` e o usuário definir `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` como `1` antes de incluir `<stdio.h>`.

Referência:

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 3):

`printf` (*print formatted*) escreve um texto formatado para o stream de saída padrão (`stdout`).

`fprintf` (*file print formatted*) escreve um texto formatado para um stream de saída que o usuário especifica.

`sprintf` (*string print formatted*) escreve um texto formatado para uma string.

`snprintf` (*safe sprintf*) o mesmo que o `sprintf`, mas não está suscetível a estouro de buffer.

Pela lógica, `printf_s` e `fprintf_s` seriam as versões seguras de `printf`e `fprintf`, respectivamente, ou seja, versões onde há verificação das posições de memória acessadas, de forma que não ocorra estouro de buffer ou acesso indevido a outra posição de memória. Porém, admito, nunca usei/nunca vi estas funções.

Você encontra bons exemplos na documentação. Exemplo: [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). Na busca, troque o nome da função e verá definição, parâmetros, tipo de retorno, exemplos e muito mais.

Espero que tenha ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

O funcionamento de todos é semelhante, então não vejo necessidade de exemplos. Presumo que você saiba usar o `printf()`. Todos usam a convenção de uma string de "máscara" seguida de um vararg, ou seja, um número variável de argumentos que atendem aos % presentes na máscara. As funções que você citou diferem basicamente no que acontece com a string de resultado.

`printf`: imprime o resultado no `stdout` (saída padrão, que no caso de execução de linha de comando é o terminal).

`fprintf`: envia o resultado para o arquivo aberto passado como primeiro parâmetro (tipo FILE).

`sprintf`: envia o resultado para um buffer, passado como primeiro parâmetro. Esta função é considerada insegura porque o resultado pode ser maior que esse buffer, principalmente se os parâmetros vararg forem fornecidos por um agente externo, abrindo a porta para uma invasão (*stack overflow*).

`snprintf`: versão segura do `sprintf`. O segundo parâmetro passado é o tamanho do buffer passado no primeiro parâmetro. Se o resultado for maior que o tamanho declarado do buffer, ele será preenchido até o limite, mas sem *stack overflow*.

`asprintf`: versão segura do `sprintf` que só é oferecida em sistemas GNU (e.g. Linux). O resultado é retornado como uma string dinamicamente alocada, no tamanho necessário. É melhor que snprintf porque não é necessário calcular o maior tamanho possível do resultado.

`printf_s`, `sprintf_s`, etc: idem as versões sem sufixo `_s`, porém algumas verificações adicionais são feitas de modo a evitar os bugs típicos ao usar-se a família `printf`:

1) veda a máscara `%n`, fonte de toda uma classe de bugs e ataques

2) verifica se algum dos parâmetros correspondentes a `%s` é NULL

3) verifica se formato ou buffer é NULL

4) verifica se o tamanho do buffer é válido

5) a função `sprintf_s` exige o tamanho do buffer como segundo parâmetro, e o resultado só é armazenado no buffer se couber, diferente de `snprintf`(`_s`) que armazena a parte do resultado que couber.