# É possível concatenar números do tipo int?

Tags: c, string, int

Por exemplo 10 e 12, concatenado ficaria 1012, isso sem ser *string*, teria que ser do tipo inteiro, pode se fazer isso?

Comment: Claro que sim. Por string é uma solução mais preguiçosa, funciona bem

Comment: Até tem o algoritmo que faça, mas não é bom pois aceita poucos dígitos devido ao limite numérico dos tipos int . Veja https://ideone.com/EpbAkx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tem, mas o algoritmo que funcione em todos os casos seria complexo, quase sempre compensa mais usar a *string* para fazer a concatenação.

Então se está esperando uma instrução ou uma função pronta na linguagem que entregue o resultado, não tem.

A base matemática que deve usar para construir o algoritmo é multiplicar o primeiro número por 10 elevado ao número de dígitos dele, no exemplo 10 tem 2 dígitos, portanto deve multiplicar por 100, aí é só somar com o segundo.

Em qualquer base numérica cada dígito à esquerda tem um peso maior em progressão geométrica de acordo com sua. Então sempre que quiser colocar dígitos à esquerda deve elevar a base (no caso 10 já que lidamos com decimal) com a posição do dígito então `1234 + 123 + 12` Você navega assim:

> 1 x 10<sup>8</sup> + 2 x 10<sup>7</sup> + 3 x 10<sup>6</sup> + 4 x
> 10<sup>5</sup> + 1 x 10<sup>4</sup> + 2 x 10<sup>3</sup> + 3 x
> 10<sup>2</sup> + 1 x 10<sup>1</sup> + 2 x 10<sup>0</sup>
>
> 1 x 100.000.000 + 2 x 10.000.000 + 3 x 1.000.000 + 4 x 100.000 + 1 x
> 10.000 + 2 x 1.000 + 3 x 100 + 1 x 10 + 1 x 2
>
> 100.000.000 + 20.000.000 + 3.000.000 + 400.000 + 10.000 + 2.000 + 300 + 10 + 2
>
> 123.412.312

Obviamente que tem que fazer o processo inverso para decompor o número em algarismos.

Se tiver alguma dúvida específica de programação enquanto estiver fazendo ele poderá fazer uma dúvida específica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Para uma solução geral, veja a resposta do @Maniero. Se precisa realmente disso corriqueiramente, compensa uma função específica sua.

<sup><sub>para saída em int, veja no final da resposta</sub></sup>

## Gerando uma *string*:

Se for para coisa rápida, como um *debug*, ou apenas uma formatação de saída, o C tem uma alternativa que é a família do `printf` e seu par `sprintf` para armazenamento.

**Exemplo**

Jogando no *stdout*:

```
printf("%02d%02d\n", v1, v2);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/NR8QDB)**.

Para gravar em um buffer:

```
sprintf( destino, "%02d%02d", v1, v2);
```

Basicamente estas funções recebem uma *string* que será interpolada, e os parâmetros a interpolar. No nosso caso:

```
┌──── % marca a posição onde entrará um valor interpolado
│┌─── significa "preencher com zero a esquerda
││┌── indica que o preenchimento deve ter 2 casas
│││┌─ indica que o valor interpolado será tratado como decimal
%02d
```

Aqui tem mais informações interessantes:

> [Quais as diferenças entre printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf, printf_s e fprintf_s?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150953/70)

## Gerando um *int*:

Se precisa de valores numéricos, a concatenação é matemática:

```
concatenado = valor1 * 100 + valor2;
```

Ou, limitando a duas casas descartando *overflow*:

```
concatenado = ( valor1 % 100 ) * 100 + ( valor2 % 100 )
```

(que é o que já está na resposta do @Maniero, apenas apliquei ao seu caso).

Answer (score 2):

Caras, apanhei pra caramba mas achei uma solução legalzinha. Eu precisava concatenar três bytes que formam um número hexa de 6 dígitos e é usado pra identificar um dispositivo.

Olha a solução. Desloquei 16 bits a esquerda no primeiro número, 8 no segundo e somei com o terceiro.

```
unsigned char v1 = 0x0B;  // 11
unsigned char v2 = 0xF8;  // 248
unsigned char v3 = 0xE9;  // 233

unsigned int r = (v1 << 16) + (v2 << 8) + (v3);

printf("Valor: %x\n", r);
```

Presta atenção ao `unsigned` dos "`char`" pois o sinalizado o primeiro bit é 1 pra positivo, o que altera o resultado. Caso queira fazer sinalizado, é melhor usar campos de bits separando o sinalizador.